# Estimating the standard deviation by simply looking at a histogram

Tags: normal-distribution, estimation, standard-deviation

I would like to make a quick, rough estimate of what a standard deviation is.

Suppose i have the following histogram
[image]

By simply looking at it, I can say that the mean is around 10 or 9.8 (middle value) which, when calculating from my dataset, is actually the 9.98.

I understand that the standard deviation is a measure that is used to quantify the amount of variation or dispersion of a set of data values.

How can I estimate the standard deviation by simply looking at the histogram?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It obviously depends on the distribution, but if we assume that the distribution at hand is fairly normal, the [full width at half maximum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_width_at_half_maximum) (FWHM) is easy to eye-ball, and as is stated in the given link, it relates to the standard deviation $\sigma$ as 
$$FWHM \approx 2.36\sigma$$
for a normal distribution.

*Edit:* Let's try to apply this for your distribution. I'd say that the *full* maximum of your distribution is around 0.08, so the half maximum is 0.04. Now all the need to figure out is the width at that height, which I'd say is approximately 10. Using the formula above, we find that $$\sigma\approx \frac{10}{2.36}\approx4.24.$$

Comment: From the formulae youve given the value am trying to figure out is σ. How can i estimate it by simply looking at the histogram.Just an approxiamation

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI I'll edit my answer to provide an example.

Comment: Just to clarify does it mean that the value 10 (width at maximum height) is the value on the x axis of the largest bar.

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI No, the width of the distribution at the half height is the distance on the $x$-axis between the two points at which the distribution is equal to the half height. Say your distribution function is called $f(x)$ and that the max of this function is $f_{max}=0.08.$ Then you have two solutions $x_1$ and $x_2$ to the equation $f_{max}/2=f(x),$ and the distance $|x_2-x_1|$ is then your FWHM. In your case, $x_1\approx 5$ and $x_2\approx 15,$ so the result happened to be $10.$ Also, look at the picture in the wiki-article, it is much easier to see there.

Comment: Thanks ive now got it. Also a quick calculation from the original data provides standard deviation as 4.3 so 4.24 is a pretty good estimate.

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI That's good to hear :)

Answer (score 1):

Assume normal distribution where 99.7% (~100%) of values fall [within 3 standard deviations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule) from the mean. This implies your $x_{min}$ and $x_{max}$ values define the full span of the domain and are each roughly 3 standard deviations from the mean, leading to:

$$ \sigma = \frac{x_{max} - x_{min}}{6} $$

In above case, $\sigma \approx \frac{20 - (-5)}{6} \approx 4.17$